# What does とな mean (and how do I use it)?

Tags: usage, vocabulary, colloquial-language, definitions

I came across this on Twitter, it seems to be mostly a question but sometimes an exclamation. Is it とは, or maybe とか? How do you use it? My dictionary has a とな as word that come at the end of a sentence to get confirmation. Is this the same?

[画像も貼らずにスレたてとな？](https://twitter.com/sosei920/status/78955392306122752)
[今日は次第に雨とな。](https://twitter.com/ookumaneko_mdk/status/78943263511412736)
[千葉東方沖震度4とな？](https://twitter.com/momijiya/status/78930304471007232)
[むっちゃんがイケメン店員とな(￣□￣)!?](https://twitter.com/bnnseven/status/78950641476714496)

The avatars of people using it are [overwhelmingly cute](https://twitter.com/#search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA). Is this a cute word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As YOU wrote, とな in these examples is a combination of the particle と signifying quotation and the particle な signifies that the speaker wants reply or agreement or wants to make sure.  I think that とな in this meaning is rare in the modern Japanese except as an Internet slang or possibly in some dialects.

“画像も貼らずにスレ立てとな!?” is a set phrase used in some Internet forums including [2channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2channel).  It means something similar to “You started a new thread (in the forum) without even including a single image in it?  Seriously?”  I guess that many of the uses of “とな!?” (or “とな?”) are inspired by this set phrase.

Answer (score 6):

とな is basically formed by combination of と and な.

You may use ～とな　at the end of the sentenses like that, basically use when you heard it from somewhere else and also express your agreement when you repeat that. It has similar meaning with ～というのだね.

You may also use ～とな at the end of the phrase (even in the middle of sentence), and it express light emphasis for your agreement.

ref:

- [http://www.weblio.jp/content/とな](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA) 「大辞林」

Comment: @Boaz, btw, will you be ok for [this moderator nominations about yours](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/127/moderator-pro-tempore-nomination/175#175)?, if so, could you comment as you accept it, and may be also an upvote?