# What is な-particle doing in `ってなわけで`?

Tags: set-phrases, colloquial-language, contractions

I noticed that `ってなわけで` is commonly used as a substitute for `というわけで` in colloquial speeches, but what exactly is the purpose of the な-particle in that phrase? Does it make the context that the phrase refers to adjective-ish, like suggested in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/using-%E3%81%AA-particle-after-common-nouns-non-na-adjectives/1562#1562)?

Or is it actually the な-particle that is similar in usage to the one in `それなのに`? How does the construction work though?

Comment: I think you misheard `てなわけで`. More accurately, the expression you are asking is probabaly `ってなわけで`.

Comment: @sawa: I do not think that we should edit the question to correct でなわけで (inaccurate) to ってなわけで (accurate), because that is the integral part of the question.

Comment: I kind of agree with the edit; I think the focus of the question is (was) the role of な, not the role of で or って, and the typo was a distraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crucial part you are asking is `ってな`. As you suggest, it is a colloquial version of `という` that introduces an appositive clause. They are probably interchangable. The noun is not limited to `わけ`, but has to be able to take an appositive clause.

> という話, ということ, というわけ, という理由, という記事, という理屈, という説明, という計画, という作戦
>   　ってな話, ってなこと, ってなわけ, ってな理由, ってな記事, ってな理屈, ってな説明, ってな計画, ってな作戦

Furthermore, `って` is a colloquial version of `と` that introduces a subordinate clause.

> ...と思う
>   ...って思う

It can also be a colloquial version of the topic particle `は`.

> あの人はかっこいい。
>   あの人ってかっこいい。

`な` is probably related to the `な` that introdoces a na-adjective in attributive position. But that does not explain why it is used together with `って`. Somehow, `とな` is ungrammatical. Maybe you can just consider the whole `ってな` as a fixed expression.

Comment: I see, so it was (って/と)な? This とな, is there any chance that it's related to the [sentence-ending particle とな](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/899/what-does-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa-mean-and-how-do-i-use-it), or even contraction of 「となる」?

Comment: The な in とな is gobi/sentence-final, so I think that one's unlikely, at least.

Comment: Hyperworm is right. the な is used to head an attributive clause, and is different from the な in とな.