# Meaning of てなわけで at the start of a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

This sentence is the start of a new paragraph. The ellipses are as written:

> ...**てなわけで**、まる子は、カブトムシの幼虫を廊下のすみに置いたプラスチックの水槽で飼っていたのだったが...。それから一か月。
>   ??? Maruko was raising the Rhinoceros Beetle grubs in a plastic fish tank that she'd put in the corner of the hallway, but... . A month went by.

I don't understand what てなわけで means. I read [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/what-is-%E3%81%AA-particle-doing-in-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7), but was unenlightened since I can't understand というわけで either.

My guess is that the わけ part together with the のだった part later on suggest that the narrator is explaining the reason for something. Later sentences got on to say that she forget to look after them for a month.

Comment: I know what it means, but let me ask this just in case.  Is there any mention of beetle raising in the preceding paragraph?  I ask because there are two different ways to use this phrase.   One is more "traditional" and logical and the other, highly colloquial.

Comment: @l'électeur Yes. The whole story (so far) is about Maruko raising beetles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「てな」 comes from 「というような」

It is a rather drastic phonetic change, but you have already encountered the と-to-て change before, correct?  So, we know we are dealing with quotative particles (と & て).

> 「てなわけで」＝「というようなわけで」（≒「というわけで」）

Both phrases mean "***with that being said***".  Depending on the context, "***for that reason***" would fit better as 「わけ」 can mean "reason".  A freer and more informal TL would be "***so***", believe it or not.

It seems to me that "so" might not be such a bad TL for the context in question, but it is really your choice.

In very informal situations in real life, people often start a conversation with 「てなわけで」 or 「というわけで」 without barely explaining what it is that they want to talk about.  This is what I was talking about in my comment above.

Comment: This question makes me think of ということで when you start saying something (I remember a boss i had that used to say it all the time). Do you think it can be considered equivalent to というわけで?