# How I should parse/translate てなことで at start of sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

The sentence is

> てなことで、修行なんてしなくとも、ただ飯を食っているだけで強くなれるんだな。

Google translates first part as "By the way". But I can't find any information how it should be parsed. I think its probably "てな こと で", but only translation of "てな" seems to be this, which doesn't match:

> てな; ってな; てね; ってね (prt) (used at end of sentence) (apparently) that's what it's like, isn't it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This てな is a highly colloquial variant of という or というような. てなことで is the same as ということで, which in this context means "therefore" or "for this reason", not "by the way".

> **てなことで**、修行なんてしなくとも、ただ飯を食っているだけで強くなれるんだな。
> **Therefore**, even if you don't train, you can get stronger just by eating and spending time.

Related:

- [Meaning of てなわけで at the start of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41231/5010)
- [ということで in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54875/5010)